# Type mismatch. Required: (RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>?..RecyclerView.Adapter<*>?) Found: ListDemonAdapter

Tags: android, kotlin

I Have problems in this line, and i get stuck for it.

Here is Main Activity

```
package com.example.dicoding
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.Menu
import android.view.MenuItem
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.dicoding.ListDemonAdapter
import com.example.dicoding.R
import com.example.dicoding.demonlisr

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var rvDemon: RecyclerView
    private val list = ArrayList<demonlisr>()
    private var usingGrid = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.mainactivity)
        rvDemon = findViewById(R.id.top10)
        rvDemon.setHasFixedSize(true)

        list.addAll(getListDemon())
        showRecyclerList()

    }



    private fun getListDemon(): ArrayList<demonlisr> {
        val dataName = resources.getStringArray(R.array.data_name)
        val dataDescription = resources.getStringArray(R.array.data_description)
        val dataPhoto = resources.obtainTypedArray(R.array.data_photo)
        val listDemon = ArrayList<demonlisr>()
        for (i in dataName.indices) {
            val demon = demonlisr(dataName[i], dataDescription[i], dataPhoto.getResourceId(i, -1))
            listDemon.add(demon)
        }
        return listDemon
    }

    private fun showRecyclerList() {
        rvDemon.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        val listDemonAdapter = ListDemonAdapter(list)
        rvDemon.adapter = listDemonAdapter

        listDemonAdapter.setOnItemClickCallback(object : ListDemonAdapter.OnItemClickCallback {
            override fun onItemClicked(data: demonlisr) {
                showSelectedDemon(data)
            }
        })
    }

    private fun showSelectedDemon(demon: demonlisr) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Kamu memilih " + demon.name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.action_list -> {
                usingGrid = !usingGrid
                if (usingGrid){
                    rvDemon.layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
                }else{
                    rvDemon.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
                }

            }
            R.id.action_grid -> {
                val moveIntent = Intent(this@MainActivity, aboutme::class.java)
                startActivity(moveIntent)
            }
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

and here is the listdemonadapter.kt

```
package com.example.dicoding

import android.content.Intent
import android.view.View
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class ListDemonAdapter(private val listdemon: ArrayList<demonlisr>){
    private lateinit var onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback

    fun setOnItemClickCallback(onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback) {
        this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback
    }

    class ListViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imgPhoto: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_detail_photo)
        val tvName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_detail_name)
        val tvDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_detail_description)
    }

    fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val (name, description, photo) = listdemon[position]
        holder.imgPhoto.setImageResource(photo)
        holder.tvName.text = name
        holder.tvDescription.text = description


        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val context = holder.itemView.context
            val intentDetail = Intent(holder.itemView.context, description::class.java)
            intentDetail.putExtra("key_demon", listdemon[holder.adapterPosition])
            holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intentDetail)
            context.startActivity(intentDetail)
        }



    }

    interface OnItemClickCallback {
        fun onItemClicked(data: demonlisr)
    }
}
```

i got error in line

```
 rvDemon.adapter = listDemonAdapter
```

which it make outputs
Type mismatch: inferred type is ListDemonAdapter but RecyclerView.Adapter<(raw) RecyclerView.ViewHolder!>? was expected

i try to change variables of rvDemon to RvDemon but still fail, i try to make many changes but still fail

Answer (score 0):

Just change your adapter code this way it will work

```
class ListDemonAdapter(private val listdemon: ArrayList<demonlisr>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<ListDemonAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {
    private lateinit var onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback

    fun setOnItemClickCallback(onItemClickCallback: OnItemClickCallback) {
        this.onItemClickCallback = onItemClickCallback
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ListViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.<Your Item View Layout>, parent, false)

        return ListViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listdemon.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ListViewHolder, position: Int) {
        
        holder.bind(listdemon[position])    
        
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            val context = holder.itemView.context
            val intentDetail = Intent(holder.itemView.context, description::class.java)
            intentDetail.putExtra("key_demon", listdemon[holder.adapterPosition])
            holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intentDetail)
            context.startActivity(intentDetail)
        }
    }


    class ListViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val imgPhoto: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_detail_photo)
        val tvName: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_detail_name)
        val tvDescription: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_detail_description)

        fun bind(demonlisr: demonlisr) {
            val (name, description, photo) = listdemon[position]
            imgPhoto.setImageResource(photo)
            tvName.text = name
            tvDescription.text = description
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickCallback {
        fun onItemClicked(data: demonlisr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You to extend the recycler view adapter in you adapter class

You made it like this :

```kotlin
    ....
    class ListDemonAdapter(private val listdemon: ArrayList<demonlisr>){
    ....
```

Notice here this class doesn't extend any other class aka **The recycler view adapter**

---

When you want to make any adapter for the recycler view your have a couple of options :

You can use the Default adapter for the recycler view, which will look like this:

```
class ListDemonAdapter(private val listdemon: ArrayList<demonlisr>) :
RecyclerView.Adapter<ListDemonAdapter.ListViewHolder>() {
```

as [Geek Tanmoy answred](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77768451/18121860)

or you can use another adapter which is called listAdapter which will look something like this for example:

```
class FlowerAdapter : ListAdapter<String, FlowerAdapter.FlowerViewHolder>(FlowerDiffCallback)
```

You can know more about it [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/adapting-to-listadapter-341da4218f5b)

Some of its features is :

- Animating the items
- Handling the submitted list more efficiently

but it is more advanced, I recommend sticking with the regular adapter until you learn it then you can learn the listAdapter

I hope this helps.